# Counter Loop not working

Tags: java, loops, linked-list, counter

this method is designed to add to a counter every time an item in a `linked list` equals a given element, in my case, elem.

I have;

```
public int count(E elem) {
    Node <E> current = new Node <E>();
    current = head;
    int counter = 0;

    if (current == null) {
        return 0; //current is null
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++){
            if (elem == current){
                counter++;
                head = current.getNext();
            }
    }
    return counter;
    }



public static void main(String[] args) {

    SLinkedListExtended<String> x = new SLinkedListExtended<String>();

    x.insertAtTail("abc");
    x.insertAtTail("def");
    x.insertAtTail("def");
    x.insertAtTail("xyz");
    System.out.println(x.count("def")); // should print "2"
    x.insertAtTail(null);
    x.insertAtTail("def");
    x.insertAtTail(null);
    System.out.println(x.count("def")); // should print "3"
    System.out.println(x.count(null)); // should print "2"
}
}
```

But when run, it returns 0 every time. I have looked over my loop and cannot figure out where i'm going wrong

Comment: We need the rest of your SLinkedListExtended class.  But if `head` is null, then current will be null also.  Which will always return a zero.  But we need to see the rest of the class to know for sure.

Comment: Since you're dealing with objects, you should use the `equals(...)` method, not the `==` operator.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I noticed that too, but it depends on whether you wang to allow duplicates. I tend to agree though.

Answer (score 3):

In your for loop you are comparing a `Node<E>` to an `E`.  They won't ever be equal.

Answer (score 2):

Three issues:

1. `elem == current` elem is of type E, current is of type Node.  They won't be equal.  You presumably want something like `current.getElement()`.
2. You should use `.equals()` for that comparison, eg `elem.equals(current.getElement())`. Note that even with out this your test will likely work, but only because you're checking Strings and they're a special case (look up String interning)
3. Your loop isn't moving through the list.  You have `head = current.getNext();` you want `current = current.getNext()`

Comment: Ok, i've done this. Still getting 0, and then a nullpointerexception. My method is now public int count(E elem) {
  Node <E> current = new Node <E>();
  current = head;
  int counter = 0;
  
  if (current.equals(null)) {
   return 0; //current is null
  }
  
  for (int i = 0; i<size; i++){
    if (elem.equals(current.getElement())){
     counter++;
     current = current.getNext();
    }
  }
  return counter;
  }

Comment: You need to consider what variables may be null.  If `current` can be null, then you don't want to call methods on it before checking for that.  So the first `if` should remain as you originally had it: `current == null`.  If `Node.getElement` can be null, then you need to check separately for that case, something like `if (current.getElem() == null && elem == null) counter++`.